# viewflipper problem with the second view

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am newbie to android and I couldn't able to solve  a problem with the view-flipper. when I click a button in second view the third view should appear with infromright() animation. But at the same time the first view also appearing with the third view and translating inside and disappearing. This should not happen

How to stop this, any Idea

here is the code

```
public class gif extends Activity {
    ViewFlipper flipper;
  //    RelativeLayout r1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.second_view);



    private Animation inFromTopAnimation() {

    Animation inFromTop = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    inFromTop.setDuration(1000);
    inFromTop.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromTop;
    }
    private Animation outToBottomAnimation() {
    Animation outtoBottom = new TranslateAnimation(
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f
    );
    outtoBottom.setDuration(1000);
    outtoBottom.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoBottom;
    }

    private Animation outToTopAnimation() {
    Animation inFromTop = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    inFromTop.setDuration(1000);
    inFromTop.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromTop;
    }
    private Animation outFromBottomAnimation() {
    Animation outFromBottom = new TranslateAnimation(
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f
    );
    outFromBottom.setDuration(1000);
    outFromBottom.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outFromBottom;
    }



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
     ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

     Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flipback);

     imgview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             flipper.setInAnimation(inFromTopAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToBottomAnimation());
             flipper.showNext();      
         }
     });

     button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             flipper.setInAnimation(outToTopAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outFromBottomAnimation());
             flipper.showPrevious();

         }

     });


    }

     @Override
     public  void  onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);                                        
     imgview1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.topimageview);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview1.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation.stop();
        frameAnimation.start();
     }

     ImageView imgview2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview2);                                        
     imgview2.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview2.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.rectbackground);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation1 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview2.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation1.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation1.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation1.stop();
        frameAnimation1.start();
     } 
     ImageView imgview3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview3);                                        
     imgview3.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview3.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background1);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation2 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview3.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation2.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation2.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation2.stop();
        frameAnimation2.start();
     }
     ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview01);                                        
     imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation3 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgView.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation3.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation3.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation3.stop();
        frameAnimation3.start();
     }
     ImageView imgview02 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview02);                                        
     imgview02.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview02.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background3);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation5 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview02.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation5.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation5.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation5.stop();
        frameAnimation5.start();
     }

     ImageView imgview03 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview03);                                        
     imgview03.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview03.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background2);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation4 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview03.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation4.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation4.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation4.stop();
        frameAnimation4.start();
     }

     ImageView imgview04 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview4);                                        
     imgview04.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview04.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background4);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation6 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview04.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation6.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation6.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation6.stop();
        frameAnimation6.start();
     }
    ;
    final ImageView hearttap =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hearttap);
  // final View second = null ;

    Button ekgbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ekgbutton);

    final ImageView i2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview02);
     final ImageView i3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview03);
     final ImageView i4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview04);
     final ImageView i5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview05);
     final ImageView i6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview06);
     final ImageView i7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview07);


    hearttap.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

            Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f

            );
            inFromRight.setDuration(500);
            inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            return inFromRight;
            }
            private Animation outToLeftAnimation() {
            Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f,
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
            );
            outtoLeft.setDuration(500);
            outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            return outtoLeft;
            }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  r1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            i2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i7.setVisibility(View.GONE); 



             flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
             flipper.showNext();

           //  flipper.getChildAt(2)
             flipper.setDisplayedChild(2);


           // WebView  webview1= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.ekgwebview1);
        //   webview1.loadUrl("C://Users/Android/Desktop/bg only.gif");
         // flipper.clearDisappearingChildren();

        // flipper.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(2);
             flipper.setEnabled(true);

             if (hearttap.onTouchEvent(event))


                 return true;
             else
                 return false;         

        }
    });

 ekgbutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     private Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {
            Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
            );
            inFromLeft.setDuration(500);
            inFromLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            return inFromLeft;
            }
            private Animation outToRightAnimation() {
            Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f,
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
            );
            outtoRight.setDuration(500);
            outtoRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            return outtoRight;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i7.setVisibility(View.GONE);    

            flipper.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
             flipper.showPrevious(); 
             flipper.setEnabled(true);

             //  flipper.getChildAt(0);
            flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);

            return true;

        }

    });

    }
    }
```